# Java NullPointerException on conditional null check

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a very basic method as a part of a binary search tree which simply returns True if the current binary node has a right child or False if that right child points to null.

```
public boolean hasRight(){
    if(right.element != null){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

However whenever I test this code, the moment that I know I will reach a node that does not have a right child, and would expect my code to just return False, java throws a NullPointerException at the line

```
    if(right.element != null)
```

instead of returning False like I would expect it to.

Edit:

Fixed my code, simply had to check right itself being null before trying to get the element of right

```
public boolean hasRight(){
    if(right != null){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it display when you do `if (right == null) {...}` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Then `right` itself is `null`.  Check for that first before attempting to access something on it.

```
if (right != null && right.element != null){
```

Answer (score 5):

if `right` is null, you cannot access `right.element()`.

btw: Your method can be easier written as

```
hasRight(){
   return right != null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting a `NullPointerException`, then `right` should be `null`. So you could do this:

```
if(right != null && right.element != null){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```